# Proxy request to Graphql API

Tags: node.js, proxy, graphql

I want to request data from an external graphql API from my client. I have to make the request to my server first and from there proxy it to the external API. What would be the best way to do this, is there maybe a package that does this for you ?

My research has lead me to something called gateways , whats the difference between a gateway and a proxy?

When do i need which?